# Fill in a text box when selecting a combo box option on Access

Tags: vba, combobox

Im not very advanced in Access and I am struggling with defining  the VBA code/expression build/ or Control Source for an instruction that can make the following isntruction:

- **If** i make a  selection on a *Combo box* (with my key field "TypeService"  on my table TblMain)
- **Then**; my *text box* is able to return  the TypeConfig rows related to the TypeService selected before (my table TblConfig contains TypeServiceFK and TypeConfig fields)

So, my objective is to get a dynamic textbox that depends of a multi option combobox.-

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You want multiple rows (potentially) from tblConfig to be in a textbox? Any reason you wouldn't use a listbox for that?

Comment: Ja, sorry, thats what i meant to say, is a list box that i wanna display with the options... and it is many rows... so the user can seleect one or/and many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a listbox on your form, let's say it's called List2, and cancel the wizard if it pops up.

In the Row Source property of the listbox, put this SQL statement

```
SELECT tblConfig.TypeConfig FROM tblConfig WHERE (((tblConfig.TypeService)=[Forms]![frmMain]![Combo0]));
```

This assumes your form is called `frmMain` and your combobox is called `Combo0`, so change those as necessary.

Right click on Combo0 and choose Build Event, then Code Builder. Replace the `Sub...End Sub` stub with

```
Private Sub Combo0_Change()

    Me.List2.Requery

End Sub
```

Now every time Combo0 changes, the SQL statement behind List2 will run and return the TypeConfigs associated with that TypeService.

Comment: Thnks so much for ur answr!  im working all this on a report... Will it work anyways?

Comment: Yes, it should still work. But generally reports just display information and there is no selecting from comboboxes or listboxes. I'm not sure what you're doing, but you might consider making a form where the user makes selections and then generate a report from there.

Comment: Im making a report that contains steady text, info from the forms and info from databases.... Thats why i need that if the user select determined options in a form , it displays the textboxs, and is been able to pick... And that config after displays in the report...