# problem when try to Automatically fill in Access text boxes based on a combo box selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello every one please can you help me
I tried this code

```
=DLookUp("[b]","table1","[table1].[a] = " & Str([Combo332].[Text]))
```

in access form
to get value b from table1 based on combobox to put it in text box in the control sourse
but when I change the value in combobox I get nothing in textbox I get this `#Type!`

can some one help me thanks

Comment: Don't use .Text. Why are you using Str() function? What data type is [a]? Are these your real object names? Instead of DLookup(), include field b as a column in combobox then reference that column with expression in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: I solved it by this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416350/fill-in-a-text-box-when-selecting-a-combo-box-option-on-access?rq=1
thanks

Comment: Glad you got it working but why use VBA when there is an option without it?